# Preventing chocolate from burning, when its used as the crust of a New York style cheesecake

Tags: baking, chocolate, cheesecake

I am using this flour-less chocolate cake recipe as the crust of a New York style cheesecake. [Cake recipe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sTQoTgMZMk)
The full recipe is in the youtube description, if you didn't feel like watching it, and the only alteration I am doing is switching out the alcohol with Malibu Rum.

The cheesecake recipe is here [Cheesecake Recipe](http://www.joyofbaking.com/Cheesecake.html)

What I do is bake the cake first, then I pour the cheesecake over that and follow it's baking directions.

The problem I am having is that the chocolate burns in a couple of places at the bottom of the pan. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

A few things I noticed:

1. The cooking times/temps are different... You need to somehow account for that. 350 for 15 min and 250 for 60-90 vs 350 for 25-30 min is a pretty big difference it seems. I'm not experienced to know how to modify it...
2. The chocolate recipe specifies cooking in a water bath. The cheesecake recipe does not. I would definitely cook my cheesecake in a water bath. I have had great luck with the techniques described in [The cheesecake episode of Good Eats.](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/Season5/Cheesecake/CheesecakeTranscript.htm)
3. Have you thought abou using a more standard chocolate cookie based crust and making a sauce with the similar chocolate/liquor flavours?